# Integrity of Request/X509 Alternative Name/Extension Information

Tags: ssl, openssl, x509, asn.1

Am I correct in assuming that there's protection against the modification of both the subject and the extension information in a request or X509 certificate?

This signature is just another element embedded in the ASN.1 encoding?

Comment: Yes, all the data is signed and checked when the certificate is validated.

Comment: No. The Issuer will copy the subject's fields and extensions that he/she wants from the request. There's no guarantee that all the fields you specify in the subject or extensions of the request will be present in the certificate that is issued. Intuitively: do you think an issuer will sign a certificate with bits set so that your cert becomes an intermediate CA to use for more signing?

Comment: @jww Make sure you read the question before you so eagerly supply an answer.

Comment: Dustin - not sure what you mean. Your title indicates you are interested in the request's SAN. Is that not the case?

Comment: I'm interested in the integrity of the extension information. In other words, that I can trust that it hasn't been altered. That was also implied by the other answers and comments.

Comment: @DustinOprea: I get you are interested in the integrity of the extension information. However, you *clearly* asked about a request. So we are on the same page: a request is a Certificate Signing Request or CSR. If that's not the case, then you should edit your question to avoid confusion.

Comment: - Here's the RFC for a CSR: [Certification Request Syntax Specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2986.txt). There is no signature in `CertificationRequestInfo`, so the issuer may tamper with your request's data.

Comment: Thanks for this, @jww. Generally speaking, you'll probably have to be your own CA, anyway, to guarantee that your extensions aren't filtered out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expound @Eugene's comment:

[RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280) on *Internet X.509 Public Key Infrastructure Certificate and Certificate Revocation List (CRL) Profile* specified a certificate as:

```
Certificate  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
    tbsCertificate       TBSCertificate,
    signatureAlgorithm   AlgorithmIdentifier,
    signatureValue       BIT STRING  }

TBSCertificate  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
    version         [0]  EXPLICIT Version DEFAULT v1,
    serialNumber         CertificateSerialNumber,
    signature            AlgorithmIdentifier,
    issuer               Name,
    validity             Validity,
    subject              Name,
    subjectPublicKeyInfo SubjectPublicKeyInfo,
    issuerUniqueID  [1]  IMPLICIT UniqueIdentifier OPTIONAL,
                         -- If present, version MUST be v2 or v3
    subjectUniqueID [2]  IMPLICIT UniqueIdentifier OPTIONAL,
                         -- If present, version MUST be v2 or v3
    extensions      [3]  EXPLICIT Extensions OPTIONAL
                         -- If present, version MUST be v3
    }
```

> Am I correct in assuming that there's protection against the modification of both the subject and the extension information in a request or X509 certificate?

I am not sure what kind of request you exactly mean but in a X509 certificate both the `subject` and the `extensions` are part of the `tbsCertificate` which is signed by `signatureValue` which indeed is a *protection against the modification*.

Comment: Both the CSR and the X509 can have extensions. My question is about whether they both have signatures that describe their extensions. Having looked at the ASN1 structure, it looks like it.

Comment: Yes, a CSR also is signed, actually in a very similar manner, the `CertificationRequest` corresponds to the `Certificate` and the `CertificationRequestInfo` to the `TBSCertificate`.